# Data update in UI is delayed by 8 seconds

Tags: swift

I receive the data from server using "globalQueue.async" and then I use the result to update the UI. I receive the desired data from server almost the same second I make the request and I know this as I print the data in XCode through code. But the problem is that the UILabel in the UI is updating after at least 8 seconds.

I understand Im trying to update a side thread data on main thread but I took this approach because the UI was freezing while fetching the data from server (Nothing works during the time it tries to get data from server, and when the data is received it shows the data and enables the UI) this happens when I use "DispatchQueue.main.async" so I decided to use "globalQueue.async" as it it doesnt freezes the UI but Im facing problem with "globalQueue.async" as it updates the data on UI very late and sometimes it fails to update the data on the UI even when the data was printed in XCode.

Im lost, I tried for days with lots of headache  and I cant figure out a way to achieve my target to fetch data from server and update the UI without freezing the UI in the process even for a second.

Please help.

Here is the ViewController.swift code:

```
try! myobj.createData(request: request, with: { stringReturn in
        print("" + stringReturn.result)
        self.displayTextArea.text = stringReturn.result// displayTextArea is UILabel field                
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every UI Update must be done in the main thread
try this...

```
try! myobj.createData(request: request, with: { stringReturn in
    print("" + stringReturn.result)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.displayTextArea.text = stringReturn.result// displayTextArea is UILabel field                
            }
     })
```